# In assembly, how do I add a 5 byte instruction into a 3 byte space in the debugger

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to change this line

```
0041DE91 | 8B 46 64                 | mov eax,dword ptr ds:[esi+64]  
0041DE94 | 83 C4 0C                 | add esp,C                                   
0041DE97 | 83 F8 01                 | cmp eax,1
```

to

```
0041DE91 |  mov eax, 10
```

But the instruction which was 3 bytes occupies 5 bytes and spills into the two addresses below it:

```
0041DE91 | B8 0A 00 00 00           | mov eax,10                                    
0041DE96 | 0C 83                    | or al,83                                    
0041DE98 | F8                       | clc
```

Is it possible to do this in a debugger to a pre-compiled program?

Comment: no. not without hacking up the rest of the code AFTER the insertion point to move everything 2 bytes over. or hoping that some other register contains a zero so you don't need to embed a 32bit "zero" in there.

Comment: Now you're thinking. I need any number that's not zero in the register.

Comment: why not `xor eax,eax`? that'll zero out the register only only use a byte or two.

Comment: I want the opposite. A non zero number in the register. Your idea is all I needed. Just add any other register. I accidentally copied over 0, I meant 10 in the example above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 32-bit code (where there's no [red-zone](/questions/tagged/red-zone) to clobber) you can move imm8 constants into registers (inefficiently) with 3 bytes:

```
push   10       ; 2B
pop    eax      ; 1B
```

You can also get `1` into a register in 3B

```
xor    eax, eax  ; 2B
inc    eax       ; 1B
```

Or, given any other register of known contents:

```
lea    eax, [ecx+/-imm8]   ; 3B
```

Other code-golf / code-size-optimization tricks:

```
xor    eax,eax   ; 2B
cdq              ; 1B to zero edx as well
```

```
xchg   eax, ecx  ; 1B.  Shorter than MOV if you want ecx=eax and can trash eax (or both parts are actually useful)
```

Many of these are applicable to 16-bit and 64-bit code as well.  See for example my [adler32 in 32B of x86-64 machine code, and the x86-16 version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78896/compute-the-adler-32-checksum/78972#78972).

Comment: You said in the comment _Shorter than MOV if you want ecx=eax_ but you use generic _xchg   eax, r32_ in the code. Maybe you meant _xchg   eax, ecx_ to match the comment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: thanks, I first wrote ecx, then changed it to generic.  But I think you're right, it works better with a specific example to talk about in the comment.  (which I forgot to update, xD)

Comment: Those first two look promising, I will have to try tomorrow when I wake up. I could just increment eax since I know it will be zero but I could also also use a register holding an address( which I know won't be negative) like esi above. Lots of ways to do it now that someone got me thinking.

Answer (score 4):

If you have some spaces left around that 3-byte area you can put the new code there and do a near jump, do what you need and jump back.

That technique is used to implement hot-patching in Windows. It's done by putting `MOV EDI, EDI` as a 2-byte `NOP` at the beginning of the function. Then when the function needs to be patched, they replace that "NOP" with a `JMP $-5` and a full jump to the new function would be put in the 5 bytes before the function

- [Why do Windows functions all begin with a pointless MOV EDI, EDI instruction?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583)
- [What does "Hot Patchability" mean and what is it for?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freik/2006/03/07/what-does-hot-patchability-mean-and-what-is-it-for/)

So now basically you need to change

```
mov eax, dword ptr ds:[esi+64]
add esp, C
cmp eax, 1
```

to

```
    jmp new_instruction
continue:
    add esp, C
    cmp eax, 1
...
new_instruction:
    mov eax, 10
    jmp continue
```

With this method you can replace the original instruction any sequence of instructions. However for setting small values then Peter's solution is better

Comment: "and do a near jump," -- A near 32-bit jump doesn't fit into 3 bytes. Perhaps you meant a short jump (2 bytes).

Comment: @ecm yes. I thought 32-bit jump is the far jump